# Pop3 settings UiPath

Tags: uipath

I have been trying to get the pop3 activities working on UiPath on an AWS server. I have put in the username, password and host name as webmail.server.co.uk but it seems to time out. I've tried both https and leaving that out.

Comment: Have you tried opening the port on your VPS that is required to connect to the server? Are you using the right type of authentication and the right type of connection?

Comment: Have you tried using the same information to logon via another program - like outlook or thunderbird? Just to check that you are using the right settings?

Comment: Thanks guys. It was both vps and I didn't notice the connection type. Fixed and working. Woohoo.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port needed opening and authentication needed to be set. Thanks for the helpful answers.